# What's happening during splash-screen of flutter app?

Tags: ios, flutter, splash-screen

I submitted my flutter application to Apple.
They rejected it because it froze during the splash screen which I can't reproduce. When I look at my sentry, I don't see errors.

So I was wondering, When does the `main.ts` run? Is it right after you launch the app, during the splash screen or after the splash-screen?

Comment: iOS apps do not have a "splash screen". Do you mean the launch screen? Did you test with no network and/or slow network? Because I assure you that Apple does.

Comment: Yes I meant launch screen. Yeah. I did not test it on slow network. I'll test it. Thanks @matt